# Having a hard time proving this inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given $a \in (0,\infty)$, $x_{0} \in R^{n}$, let $x,y \in R^{n}$ be such that $|x-x_{0}|\leq a$ and $|y-x_{0}|>a$.

I need to prove that
$$\Bigg| x - \Big(x_{0} + a \frac{ y - x_{0}}{|y-x_{0}|}\Big)\Bigg| \leq |x-y|$$

I'm trying to prove it since yesterday and I still couldn't. I've been trying to "add zeros" (like $+ x_{0} - x_{0}$) and then use the triangle inequality and the reverse triangle inequality, but it have got me nowhere.

Can anybody give me a tip ?

Thanks!

$\textbf{EDIT}$: Thank you all for helping me with this one. I'll show you now the way I proved it:

Writing $\xi_{y}:= x_{0} + a \frac{y-x_{0}}{|y-x_{0}|}$, it follows that $|\xi_{y}-x_{0}|=a$. We have:
$(1.1) \hspace{4.5cm}|x - \xi_{y}| \leq |x - x_{0}| + |\xi_{y} - x_{0}|$

On the other hand,

$(1.2)\hspace{1cm}|y - x | = |y - x_{0} + x_{0} - x| \geq \Big| |y-x_{0}| - |x - x_{0}|\Big| = |y- x_{0}| - |x - x_{0}|$

Since $|y - x_{0}| > a = |\xi_{y}- x_{0}|$, we obtain from (1.2) the following inequality:
$(1.3)\hspace{3cm}|y-x| \geq |y- x_{0}| - |x- x_{0}| \geq |\xi_{y}- x_{0}| - |x - x_{0}|$

Using (1.1) and (1.3) we finally get
$$|y-x| \geq |x - \xi_{y}| \implies \boxed{|x - \xi_{y}| \leq |x-y|}$$

Comment: Take $n=1$. If $x=y=0,~x_0=1,~a=2$ the inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to add some hypothesis.

Comment: It is still false. LHS is not necessarily $0$ when $x=y$.

Comment: You can't have $x=y$, you have $|x-x_0|\le a$ and $|y-x_0|>a$.

Comment: @1Rock You obviously tried to address your comment to Kavi Rama Murthy. But instead you addressed it to the author of the question.

Comment: @Jean Weigel: I can post an algebraic proof, but your question already has $4$ close votes (presumably since you've shown no details of what you tried). If you edit your question to show a legitimate attempt, it might stay open, and then I'll post my solution.

Comment: @quasi I think the first three close votes were caused by incorrect formulation of the problem.

Comment: The edit should result in the question being reopened, with any luck. As for the proof: you have proved $|y-x| \geq |\xi_{y}- x_{0}| - |x - x_{0}|$ and $|x - x_{0}| + |\xi_{y} - x_{0}| \geq |x - \xi_{y}|,$ which all seems true enough, but then it looks like you've mistaken the outermost minus sign in the first inequality for a plus sign in order to derive the final inequality. (There's no need to correct the proof, because the important thing was to show your work, and you have done that.)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Oh yes, I mistyped it. Hehe, thanks my friend!!!

Comment: I think you should indicate in the body of the question why you consider your derivation to be wrong. Otherwise after the edit it is not clear what is your question about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By translation, we can assume $x_0$ is the zero vector, and by an appropriate scaling, we can assume $a=1$.

With those replacements, the goal is to prove that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $|x|\le 1 < |y|$, we have
$$
|x-u|\le|x-y|
$$
where $u$ denotes $y/|y|$.

In fact, the inequality is strict.

Letting $c=|y|$, we get $c > 1$ and $y=cu$, hence
\begin{align*}
&
2x{\,\cdot\,}u\le 2|x||u|
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2x{\,\cdot\,}u\le 2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2x{\,\cdot\,}u < c+1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(2x{\,\cdot\,}u)(c-1) < c^2-1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(2x{\,\cdot\,}u)(c-1) < (c^2-1)|u|^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
2x{\,\cdot\,}y-2x{\,\cdot\,}u < |y|^2-|u|^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
-2x{\,\cdot\,}u+|u|^2 < -2x{\,\cdot\,}y+|y|^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
|x|^2-2x{\,\cdot\,}u+|u|^2 < |x|^2-2x{\,\cdot\,}y+|y|^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
|x-u|^2 < |x-y|^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
|x-u| < |x-y|
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
as was to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\mapsto x+x_0,\quad y\mapsto y+x_0.$
Then we need to prove
$
\left|x-a\frac{y}{|y|}\right|<|x-y|,\tag1
$
provided that
$$
|x|\le a,\quad |y|>a.\tag2
$$

The inequality $(1)$ is equivalent to:
$$\begin{align}
&\left(x-a\frac{y}{|y|}\right)^2<(x-y)^2\\
\iff&2x\cdot y\left(1-\frac{a}{|y|}\right)
-y^2\left(1-\frac{a^2}{|y|^2}\right)<0\\
\iff&2|x||y|-|y|^2\left(1+\frac{a}{|y|}\right)<0\tag{*}\\
\iff&2|x|-|y|-a<0.\tag3\\
\end{align}$$
where in $(*)$ we used [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

The inequality $(3)$ readily follows from $(2)$ since: $
2|x|-|y|-a\le 2a-|y|-a=a-|y|<0.$

Comment: @amWhy Was the edit necessary?

Comment: Always thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 1):

Try to draw a geometric picture. You know $|y-x_0|>a$, so the vector $x_0+a\frac{y-x_0}{|y-x_0|}$ is a vector in the same direction as $y-x_0$, but shorter - it is the projection of that vector onto the circle of radius $a$ around $x_0$. Also, $x$ lies inside that circle. See if you can draw the picture, and work it out from there.

Comment: Thank you, @1Rock ! Your comments helped me to visualize what was going on with $y$ when we transformed it into  $x_{0} + a \frac{y-x_{0}}{|y - x_{0}|}$. It helped me to understand the problem intuitively. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, and along the lines suggested in @1rock's answer, we
have points $O, A, X, Y$ (necessarily coplanar, and possibly even
collinear) such that $A$ lies strictly between $O$ and $Y,$ and
$|OX| \leqslant |OA|$:

[image: A geometrical inequality.]

We have to prove $|XA| < |XY|.$ As @quasi points out in his answer,
this inequality is strict.

In traditional plane Euclidean geometry, this would follow by two
applications of the theorem that the larger side of a triangle is
opposite the larger angle: because
$\angle XAO \leqslant \angle AXO,$ therefore
$\angle XAO \leqslant 90^\circ$ (we can ignore the collinear case,
because this is not intended as a full proof, only as a preliminary
sketch), therefore $\angle XAY \geqslant 90^\circ,$ therefore
$\angle XAY > \angle AYX,$ therefore $|XY| > |XA|.$

This rough and incomplete sketch of a proof translates easily into
the context of a real inner product space - not, admittedly, in
all its details (this would require formalising several concepts
extraneous to the question that was asked), but by abstracting just
one idea, which remains geometrically intuitive.

Let $V$ be a real inner product space, such as $\mathbb{R}^n,$ for
some positive integer $n.$ Let $u$ be a non-zero element of $V,$
let $v$ be an element of $V$ such that $\|v\| \leqslant \|u\|,$ and
let $\lambda$ be a real number strictly greater than $1.$ Then we
prove that
\begin{equation}
\label{4384233:eq:1}\tag{1}
\|v - \lambda u\| > \|v - u\|.
\end{equation}
All we use from the rough sketch proof above is the idea that
$\angle XAO \leqslant 90^\circ.$ This translates into present terms
as
$$
\langle v - u, u \rangle \leqslant 0,
$$
which follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applied to $v$
and $u,$ because
$$
\langle v - u, u \rangle =
\langle v, u \rangle - \langle u, u \rangle
\leqslant \|v\|\cdot\|u\| - \|u\|^2 
= (\|v\| - \|u\|)\|u\| \leqslant 0. \ \square
$$
We now have
\begin{align*}
\|v - \lambda u\|^2 & = \|(v - u) - (\lambda - 1)u\|^2 \\ & =
\langle (v - u) - (\lambda - 1)u, (v - u) - (\lambda - 1)u \rangle
\\ & = \langle v - u, v - u \rangle +
(\lambda - 1)^2\langle u, u \rangle -
2(\lambda - 1)\langle v - u, u \rangle \\
& = \|v - u \|^2 + (\lambda - 1)^2\|u\|^2 -
2(\lambda - 1)\langle v - u, u \rangle \\
& > \|v - u \|^2,
\end{align*}
because $\lambda - 1 > 0,$ $\|u\| > 0,$ and
$\langle v - u, u \rangle \leqslant 0.$
This proves \eqref{4384233:eq:1}. $\ \square$

In terms of the question, take $V = \mathbb{R}^n,$ and
\begin{align*}
v & = x - x_0, \\
\lambda & = \frac{\|y - y_0\|}{a}, \\
u & = \frac{y - x_0}{\lambda}.
\end{align*}
Then $\lambda > 1$ and $\|v\| = \|x - x_0\| \leqslant a = \|u\|,$
so our hypotheses are satisfied, and
\begin{gather*}
v - \lambda u = x - y, \\
v - u = (x - x_0) - a\frac{y - y_0}{\|y - y_0\|},
\end{gather*}
so \eqref{4384233:eq:1} gives the required inequality in its strict
form. $\ \square$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It was very clarifying and helped me to visualize the big picture.